# This site can’t be reached odoo 11.0 localhost:8069 running on window OS

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-11

I installed odoo_11.0.latest.exe on win 10 from http://nightly.odoocdn.com/11.0/nightly/exe/odoo_11.0.latest.exe

I installed http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.6.1-1-windows-x64.exe, in pgAdmin I can see server in localhost:5432 (User openpg, PW openpgpwd)

I run the odoo installer with default values and when I clicked finish the browser open http://localhost:8069/ with msg `This site can’t be reached, localhost refused to connect.`

The same msg in http://localhost:8069/web/database/manager

BTW the enterprise edition was installed smoothly, but it also installed postgresql with DB odoo_tst.

How to debug this?

Comment: is you window service started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to run odoo 10 on win:

1. install vagrant and it's dependency virtualbox
2. in the cmd to: `vagrant init ubuntu/xenial32`
3. add line in Vagrantfile

   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.7"
4. vagrant reload
5. vagrant up
6. vagrant ssh
7. follow this install https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-10-on-ubuntu-16-04/
8. sudo su - postgres
9. cd /opt/odoo/odoo-10
10. odoo-bin

site should be reachable at http://55.55.55.7:8069/

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, finally I get success wit these following steps (`odoo11`):

1. Make sure you have run odoo service 
   [image]
2. Check you postgres

   [image]
3. Look at you config file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo.conf`

> ```
> .... 
> db_name = False
> db_password = openpgpwd
> db_port = 5432
> db_sslmode = prefer
> db_template = template1
> db_user = openpg
> ....
> ```

1. Access to `http://localhost:8069` and process your installation by follow the screen, and enjoy.